# Getting returned language when using fallbacks

Tags: ruby, mobility

Is there a way to get the language that the https://github.com/shioyama/mobility gem returned whe using a fallback?

e.g i have something like this

```
resource.description_backend.write(:en, "Foo")
resource.description_backend.write(:de, "bar")
resource.description_backend.write(:fr, "dummy")
...
Mobility.locale = :ja
resource.description(fallback: [:nl, :de])
```

I get the expected "bar, but i need a way to know that it is the :de value (I want to set the "Content-Language" Response Header)

Comment: There isn't a way to do this, and I'm not really sure how it could be done in a natural way (although I understand why you need it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my solution now looks like this (not really nice, but it does the job ;))

   `content_language = resource[:description].key(resource.description(fallback: [:nl, :de]))`

Comment: Ah! I see, that's interesting, you're going back from the value to the locale. But that might not work if there are translations that are the same in more than one locale... it could pick a different one. But maybe that's an edge case you can ignore.

Comment: If anyone is interested in this issue, see: https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/pull/305 There will be an api change in v1.0 (to be released soon) which will allow you to get the locale along with the value by calling the backend `read`/`write` methods.